# API - How to programmatically merge a list of merge candidates returned by .VersionControlServer.GetMergeCandidates?

Tags: api, tfs

I am creating a clone of Default Merge Window, to add a feature.

I already have a Merge candidates in a grid from command below:

```
  MergeCandidate[] candidates = tfs.GetMergeCandidates(edtSelectedSource.Text, cbxTargetBranchs.Text);
```

Now, the user selected 1 or more candidates and I need to merge them.

But the TFS API VersionControl.Merge requires source path and target path.

At first, my question, I need to iterate each candidate and merge each file of its changesets, one by one ? 
Second, how could I obtains the target path from a changeset ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the changesets are continuous, you can do it in a single merge call.  If they are not continuous, you need to submit n merges for each continuous block.  Let's say they select changesets 10, 15 and 20 and these are continuous (i.e. there are no additional candidates between that range) then you would submit a merge with a versionFrom of 10 and versionTo of 20.

As far as paths go, you want to use the ones that you passed into QueryMergeCandidates and you'll want to specify the full recursion type as well.

Comment: Now I understood the logic of api. In Merge method I need to put ChangesetVersionSpec versionFrom and versionTo as  you said:   ==> Merge(sourcePath, targetPath, ChangesetVersionSpec(changeSetIdStart), new ChangesetVersionSpec(changeSetIdEnd), LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptionsEx.None); Thank you for answer Taylor.

Answer (score 3):

First off, I've done a fair amount of programming with the TFS API, but merging is something that I would never blindly trust to automation.  Merge conflicts are best dealt with by human beings.  Yes, it's painful and can be automated in many cases, but in many others - things can go terribly wrong.  I would think twice and then twice again before  doing this on Production branches.

Here's some tips that should help:

You need to create a temp Workspace.  The Workspace is the sandbox where everything happens.  The Workspace can have files and thus, file locations associated with it.  Workspace items have rich metadata.

Have a look at the Workspace and WorkspaceInfo classes.

Then have a look at the workspace client:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.item.aspx